# How can I read jpeg file binary (without decoding) properly and save it?

Tags: python, pandas, jpeg, python-imaging-library

Actually I'd like to insert JPEG images without decoding (to save place) into a data frame (pandas) when I got stuck at the phase of loading the images properly to able to read back them with PIL.

```
from PIL import Image
with open(fname, "rb") as f:
data = f.read()
img = Image.frombytes('RGB',d,data)
```

`img = np.asarray(map(ord,img))`

I found a solution above with ord() but is a bit slow.
Is there any faster method?

I've resolved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mahotas` which is a popular library to reading/quantifying image. Install it via terminal `pip install mahotas`.

```
import mahotas as mh
import numpy as np

original_img = np.array(mh.imread('figure1.jpg'), dtype=np.float64) / 255
# check dimension, RGB
original_img.shape
Out[13]: (1536, 2048, 3)

width, height, depth = original_img.shape
# reshape 
image_flattened = np.reshape(original_img, (width*height, depth))

image_flattened.shape
Out[17]: (3145728, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however mahotas open images with decoding, as I wrote above I'd like to read it without decoding and insert it into an array (actually into pandas DataFrame) and save like that, and then read it back as array and only then decode it to an image.